# Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the class of all ordered pairs. Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the class of all ordered pairs. Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper class - that is - it is not a set [Hint: suppose for a contradiction it was a set; apply the axiom of union]

Sol: (1) Suppose for a contradiction that $z\in V(\text{class of all sets)}$ (so $z$ is a set) but $z=\mathcal{B}$.

(2) Consider $U=\bigcup\bigcup z$.

(3) By Ax. of Union (applied twice) $U$ is a set.

(4) That is $U\in V$ as the latter is the class of all sets.

(5) But now note $U=V$:

(6) Clearly $U\subseteq V$, but if $x\in V$ then $\langle x,x\rangle=\{\{x\},\{x,x\}\}\in\mathcal{B}$

(7) And then $x\in U$. So $V\subseteq U$ and therefore $V=U$.

(8) But we know that $V$ is a proper class: It cannot be any set $U$

(9) Therefore $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper class

I understand all of the steps except step (6) leading to (7), can someone please show me why this step holds.

I understand that $U\subseteq V$, but how does:

$x\in V\Rightarrow\langle x,x\rangle=\{\{x\},\{x,x\}\}\in\mathcal{B}\Rightarrow x\in U$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from the definition of a union: If $\{\{x\},\{x,x\}\}\in\mathcal B$, then $\{x\}\in\bigcup\mathcal B$, and then $x\in\bigcup\bigcup\mathcal B$.

Comment: Perfect thanks, can't believe I didn't realize that. Will accept in couple of mins.